# Magento2: How to unlock folder to folder or root directory and how to solve this?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

[image]

floder to folder lock how to slove all folder is lock in magento 2 how to unlock all floder

Comment: check permissions

Comment: I also provide permittion I dont hows all floder are lock

Comment: the directories have a lock symbol, because you don't have permission to access them

Comment: now what to do you told me ple?

Comment: correct the permissions

Comment: ple give me command bec I also provide so

Comment: this depends on how your user and webserver are configured

Comment: ok how to help me ?\

Comment: understand this: https://linuxjourney.com/lesson/file-permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the correct permission to the folders. Using the magento user (it depends on how you installed it, but usually the Magento user is 'magento'), open a terminal window and issue the following commands, one at a time. Commands must be issued from the Magento install directory:

```
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
sudo find generated -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
sudo find generated -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
sudo chown -R magento:www-data .
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

This should solve your permission problems

Comment: no such type of directory is show message all commad run